# Trying to learn recursion, don't quite understand scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```js
function isNumber(arr) {
    var result = [];
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        if (typeof arr[0] === 'number') {
            result.push(arr[0]);
            arr.splice(0, 1);
            isNumber(arr);
        } else {
            arr.splice(0, 1);
            isNumber(arr);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }

}

isNumber([1,'2','3',2]);
```

I'm trying to create a function that goes through an array and if the first item is a number it will remove it and push it to an array called result. It then calls itself again until the array is empty.

It currently returns an empty array and debugger shows that the result array keeps resetting back to an empty array.

I understand why this happens but i'm trying to figure out how to work around it.

Comment: with each call, you loose result, which you not return.

Comment: You have to pass your result array as an argument. Your `arr.length > 1` should be `arr.lenght > 0`

Comment: The real issue with this example is that it makes no sense to use recursion for this. A simple for loop would do fine.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze: Should it not be >= 1? If its >= 0 then it will error when retrieving arr[0]

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes true !

Comment: If the end goal is learn recursion... go with Fibonacci...  This realy makes no sense with recursion

Comment: What is the question? You are saying you know why you get the result you get, that implies you understand the recursion in the code but what are you trying to work around? I assume you expect the results array as output?

Comment: I understand this is a lackluster approach to try and learn recursion, but I'm just trying to understand how to actually write a function that uses recursion before I try and research use cases. I've tried googling how to learn about recursion but haven't really found any good resources.

If you guys know of any please do let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways. This one needs carrying the result array with you, but can be tail-call optimised:

```
function onlyNumbers(arr, result) {
  if (typeof result === "undefined") result = [];
  if (arr.length == 0) return result;
  let element = arr.shift();
  if (typeof element === "number") {
    result.push(element);
  }
  return onlyNumbers(arr, result);
}
```

I use a trick here to initialise the result array in the first call only. In more strict languages, I'd go with two different functions: one (nonrecursive) just to call the other one with `(arr, [])`. After the first loop, the result array is carried forward with each call, populated with each recursive call, then the call stack is unwound with `result` returned back without any changes.

The opposite is true for this pattern (simpler conceptually because you don't need the extra argument, but can't be optimised well):

```
function onlyNumbers(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return [];
  let element = arr.shift();
  let result = onlyNumbers(arr);
  if (typeof element === "number") {
    result.unshift(element);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here, we do not preconstruct the result array, but instead append the result elements (backwards!) to the return value as the stack unwinds.

Of course, recursion is the basis of functional programming. In many functional programming languages there is no other way to loop, only recursion. But that does not mean recursion stays as the primitive operation: usually those languages will build other more complex operations based on recursion, that are then used instead of naked recursion to great effect. The most basic of these are `map`, `filter` and `reduce`.

Once you understand how the recursive code works, you might want to see how `filter` is implemented through recursion, and how in JavaScript one can thus use the much simpler one-liner:

```
[1,'2','3',2].filter(x => typeof x === "number")
# => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you Amadan! Would you happen to know of any good resources where I could learn about functional programming? I've tried out Youtube and its very limited.

Comment: The benefit of recursion is to avoid intermediate values stored in local variables and only use the call stack. None of your approaches avoids them.

Answer (score 2):

To understand recursion you have to understand recursion :)

- Define terminal condition (`array.length` is 0)
- Define step (what you do on current step) how do you go deeper.

```js
function isNumber(arr) {
  // terminate recursion
  if (arr.length === 0) return []

  // step
  var first = arr[0],
    rest = arr.slice(1)

  // if first is a number concat it with the rest else next step
  return typeof first === 'number'? [first].concat(isNumber(rest)) : isNumber(rest) 
}

console.log(isNumber([1, '2', '3', 2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

result should be created outside the function, because now each function call creates a new empty result and uses the new one, not the old one, then you can check the function work into it

```
    var result = [];
    function isNumber(arr) {            
        if (arr.length > 1) {
            if (typeof arr[0] === 'number') {
                result.push(arr[0]);
                arr.splice(0, 1);
                isNumber(arr);
            } else {
                arr.splice(0, 1);
                isNumber(arr);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(result);
        }

    }

    isNumber([1,'2','3',2]);
    console.log(result);
```

if you want instead, the function to return an array with results, you should pass the array as parameter for the function and then check it after the function call

```
    function isNumber(arr, result) {            
        if (arr.length > 1) {
            if (typeof arr[0] === 'number') {
                result.push(arr[0],result);
                arr.splice(0, 1);
                isNumber(arr);
            } else {
                arr.splice(0, 1);
                isNumber(arr,result);
            }
        } 

    }

  var result=[];
  isNumber([1,'2','3',2], result);

  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result and return it.

```js
function isNumber(arr) {
    var result = typeof arr[0] === 'number' ? [arr[0]] : [];
    arr.shift();
    return arr.length ? result.concat(isNumber(arr)) : result;
}

console.log(isNumber([1, '2', '3', 2]));
console.log(isNumber([]));
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your code:

```js
function isNumber(arr, result) {
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        if (typeof arr[0] === 'number') {
            result.push(arr[0]);
            arr.splice(0, 1);
            return isNumber(arr, result);
        } else {
            arr.splice(0, 1);
            return isNumber(arr, result);
        }
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }

}

isNumber([1,'2','3',2], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense to use recursion for this matter. If you really want to do it this way then the example below is a way of doing it.

You need to pass the results array every time you call the function to store a new variable in the array so it can be returned at the end. In your current example it keeps overwriting the variable.

```js
function isNumber(arr, res) {
  // If there is no res set, create a new array
  var result = res || [];
  
  // Base case, return the result if the arr is empty
  if (arr.length <= 0) {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
  
  // Get the first element from the array (and remove it from the array)
  var firstElement = arr.shift();

  // If it's a number, add it to the array
  if (typeof firstElement === 'number') {
    result.push(firstElement);
  }
  
  isNumber(arr, result);
}

isNumber([1, '2', '3', 2]);
```

Comment: Well, it does. Filtering a data structure fits recursive scheme very well if you think about it in general case.

Comment: Of course I meant in this case specific. The result could more easily be achieved by using filter, like: `[1, '2', '3', 2].filter(function(el) { return typeof el === 'number'; });`

Comment: OP is trying to learn recursion. Filtering array (even though there is a built-in method to do it) is a perfectly valid example to learn. Even calculating array length in recursive way is ok to learn though there is `array.length`

Comment: I agree, that's why I provided my example code with comments for solving this case with recursion which might help OP understand it better